# How do I find the repo information to setup yum?

Tags: opensuse, yum

I am running openSUSE 12.3 with the KDE 4 desktop.

I am trying to install software, and most sites say to use `yum` to do it.  I try this, but it appears that I do not have any of these repositories configured for yum.  I have added one text file `repo` to the `/etc/yum.repos.d/` directory, which worked fine, but when I do not know how to find out the repository information for all of these other software packages.

The sites seem to assume that you have the repository configured already, which in my case does not appear to be true.  Can anyone explain to me the best way to get this setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, openSuSE doesn't have yum, it will have zypper.

You can install yum; however, that might not be what you want.

If you know where the repo is, you can just

```
zypper addrepo --refresh path-to-repo
```

Then you can install the software using

```
zypper in name-of-software.
```

What particular piece of software do you want to install?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a third-party repository, there should be a package with the repository information to install. Look for instructions on how to use the repository.

Be careful! Third-party repositories sometimes replace system packages, and that can cause no end of grief. Being extra they don't undergo the same level of scrutiny as the official packages, and the packages aren't in the official repositories for some reason. It might just be that nobody is interested, or it might be that the package was considered and found lacking.